# What should I call the "list of answers" a student gives in a test?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm programming an e-learning web application. Among other things, it involves tests (examinations).

On the context of this application, a *Test* is a list of *Questions*. Each *Question* is a list of *Options*, of which only one is correct.

When a student performs a test, he must choose the options he considers as valid for each of its questions. I can call every selection an *Answer*, but I'd like to find a name for the "list of answers" of the student, just like a *Test* is a "list of questions".

Is there an English word for that? Right now, I'm using "AnswerList", but I'd like to make it more concise.

Comment: Variable and class naming is off-topic as per the FAQ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Responses*, where a [response](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/response) is "an answer or reply, or something in the nature of an answer or reply", may serve.  Or *choices*, or *[replies](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reply)*.

Comment: I will go with "response", I think. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Submission** may work for you, but may be too general.

A reasonably common phrase in university examinations would be "Present your **scripts** to the invigilator at the front of the hall when you are finished." I'd question however whether this would make sense for your purposes, as the word would tend to indicate hand-written copy.

It may be appropriate for you to simply use the plural: "click the button below to submit your **answers**."

Comment: I was having doubts between submission and response, and at the end I chose the later. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reinforce analogy with pencil-and-paper testing, you could use the term **answer sheet**, which is usual in that context.

Comment: Wouldn't an *answer key* be a list of the correct answers? (Like what a teacher uses to check student papers against?) I think the OP wants a name for the list of answers generated by the student. (And at least with my kids that would rarely be 100% correct!)