# What is the correct name of a student's set of answers to a test or exam paper?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns, terminology

I am not not sure whether it should be called an answer script or an answer(ed) paper. Or are there better names?

[What should I call the “list of answers” a student gives in a test?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63230/what-should-i-call-the-list-of-answers-a-student-gives-in-a-test) just refers to a CBT situtation.

Comment: In the UK lecturers talk about *marking scripts* - so I suppose *a script*.

Comment: *Answer sheet* is what my lecturers call it.

Comment: Typo in the title? Test **or** exam paper.

Comment: Unclear.  Are you talking about the "answers" the student gives, or a "crib sheet" the student surreptitiously brings into the exam room to provide him with the answers?

Comment: I am not talking about improper activity. Some people refer to them as test or exam scripts and I swallow hard on the use of script in this sense.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Nagarajan Shanmuganathan - Answer sheet is appropriate. However if it were a verbal/oral exam then 'Response' would be appropriate i.e. The student responded by saying... or the students' response was...

Comment: I tend to think that *answer sheet* is a quite inappropriate term, at least in a humanities discipline. It seems to pre-suppose there is a correct *answer*. If the question were, for example *What were the principle causes of the French Revolution*?, there are multiple possible approaches. Historians do not agree on the matter. So your essay will not be marked for the conclusive answer you give, but for such attributes as your knowledge of the subject, evidence of wide reading,your reasoning and ability to develop an argument, your ability to write concisely and in good English etc.

Comment: In short you can write a superlative essay, but one which supplies no clear answers.

Comment: What a puzzling comment re: 'inappropriate term'. An answer is an answer, be it correct or incorrect it is still what the students' response was (written or verbalised) to the question - very few students obtain 100% in their exam papers, therefore are you inferring that a student whom when posed with a 8 mark question only scores 4 he/she has not answered the question? This maybe indeed be a lack of subject knowledge or perhaps they are (or have) run out of time to fully explain their answer... but it is still their answer!

Comment: You know very well that I am not saying that. My point is that an essay is a discursive response to a question. It does not necessarily supply "answers". Hence I do not like the term *answer paper*, as it sounds like something an 8-year-old would supply in reply to a mental arithmetic quiz.